# Sprint Boot Env Actuator Endpoint - Get current property using Javascript

Tags: javascript, spring-boot

For debugging purposes, I want to pragmatically identify the current setting of a giving property on a Spring Boot application (using the Actuator env endpoint).  As per Spring Boot specs -- a property can be set in a number of ways (via System Properties, properties files, etc). The /env/ endpoint exposes this information.  However, it exposes all properties and not just the current and actual setting.

Example output would be something like:

```
{

  "systemProperties": {
  },
  "systemEnvironment": {
    "MY_SETTING": "value2",
  },
  "class path resource [application.properties]": {
    "my.setting": "value1"
  }
}
```

**Can I safely assume that the top most setting will ALWAYS be the current one ?** I will be consuming the endpoint and want to pull just the current setting (not all of them).  I want to avoid adding specific logic to the consume service around which setting takes precedence -- though I'm not sure if this is possible, since there isn't really a concept of order in JSON.

.. and if that's the case, is there an easy way to get this using Javascript (assuming I already have the JSON consumed).  Seems like with JS the solution will either get hacky or require 3rd party lib of some sort.

Comment: Try /env/foo.property

Comment: Nice , thats works !! weird I couldn't find any documentation around it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the effective value of a property that was modified by various means (yaml, environment and so on) simply append the name of that value to the URL:

http://server:8080/env/logging.file

This works for properties that aren't of array type.

Comment: It seems to be working for boot-native properties but not for my own ones. Is there any way to get the same for custom properties?